# How do I prevent brute force SSH attacks on MacOS?

Tags: macos, ssh, security

I'm not running any special server OS, just the default MacOS 10.15 SSH daemon, with port 22 forwarded.

I looked in my `system.log` and found these entries during the middle of the night (when no known user was using the system):

```
Dec 26 01:51:39 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd...) Service exited with abnormal code: 255
Dec 26 01:51:56 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd...) Service exited with abnormal code: 255
Dec 26 01:52:04 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd...) Service exited with abnormal code: 255
Dec 26 01:52:13 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd...) Service exited with abnormal code: 255
Dec 26 01:52:20 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd...) Service exited with abnormal code: 255
... > 800 more
```

Is this the trace of a brute force attempt? How can I secure against brute force attempts with the vanilla MacOS SSH daemon?

Comment: This might be related but not certain if it implies brute force attempts or not: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/171465/sshd-service-exited-with-abnormal-code-255/329503. I've always protected against SSH server brute force attacks that have an untrusted interface by only allowing key pair with password authentication.

Comment: Most home networks cannot be accessed remotely.  Have you forwarded the port for SSH specifically? Otherwise, these failures are unlikely to be an attempt to access your machine.

Comment: Yes I have the standard port 22 forwarded.

Comment: Will legitimate SSH connections only come from some known IP addresses, such that you could allow only those through the firewall?

Comment: @NovelVentures If you setup key pair auth, you will need to get the public key from each connection you allow and add it to the authorized file or whatever. So you complicate it a little more there. If you use that and also have them connect when you get the public key to a different port say `10022` you tell the connector to connect on that port and forward accordingly in your port forward rules. In addition, you can also use the Fail2Ban as mentioned to thwart the ssh brute force attacks too. That gives you 3 levels of protection at this point. I'd still monitor logs occasionally too.

Answer (score 1):

This log message typically shows up when `sshd` denies a connection.
You're probably seeing unauthorized users trying to brute force their way in by
trying common usernames and passwords.
There used to be a log entry from `sshd` itself telling you the IP address
and username attempted, but Apple has decided to replace
standard UNIX logging in `sshd`.

I suggest that you port-forward some other port from the router,
for example router port `2222` forwarded to `22`, and close port `22` of the router.

You should examine carefully all open ports on the router
([GRC ShieldsUP!](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2)
is a good tester).
As you are under attack, don't use trivial passwords or standard user names
for SSH.

Comment: Thanks! If I configured my SSHD to only allow key-based auth, there’s basically no way for anyone to get in, right? Would it slow my computer down, if I constantly have brute force bot attempts?

Comment: No one can guarantee this as there could be holes in the SSH server  (its happen d before)  although it is a powerful first step. It will slow your computer down bit probably not noticeably.

Comment: There are never enough protections and leaving open known ports is an invitation to attack. You cannot protect against newly discovered vulnerabilities.

Comment: These are all great points, but I do want to balance convenience (having an open SSH server) with the risks (potential day zero attacks). It seems like using key-based auth is industry standard now?

Comment: Not necessarily. A long and complex password will also be effective. Other protections depend on the server, if it can block an IP after some wrong tries etc.

Answer (score 1):

Fail2Ban can frustrate brute force attacks.

A more comprehensive solution is to stop forwarding SSH and install a VPN server.  To reach the SSH connection externally people need to first connect over VPN.   This is a more complex but also more robust and flexible model.

As others have said requiring passphrases helps (also disallow root logins)  but won't stop these messages . (Although I'm not a fan, changing the port can help a bit as well)